# Combination of git revert and merge results in lost file

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I experienced strange behaviour of git merge after using revert, respectively Reverse commit action in SourceTree.

1. I added a file called 'new_file' to a master branch.
2. Then I reverted the commit in master and created branch feature/2
3. I reverted the commit on branch feature/2 as well.
4. I created 'new_file' on branch feature/2 once more.
5. I merged feature/2 into master, merge introduced no changes, file 'new_file' is not present in master.

Does anybody have any explanation for this behaviour?

Is anybody aware of any Git or Source option that changes this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Happens also if I delete the file manually and commit instead of revert in steps 2. and 3.

Comment: What were you attempting to accomplish on `feature/2`? Even without the merge you can see that `feature/2` deleted a file and then put it back to exactly how it was before, so the net change of those 2 commits is indeed "no changes".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is the expected behavior of `git merge` in your situation.

Here is a rough outline of how `git merge` works :

```
# starting point :
  * eacff2 (feature/2) Added new_file again
  * eacff1 Revert "Added new_file"
* | eacfmm (HEAD -> master) Revert "Added new_file"
|/
* eacfXX Added new_file
```

when you run `git merge feature/2`, `git` first computes the "merge base" between the current branch, `master`, and `feature/2`.
In the above diagram, it is commit `eacfXX Added new_file`.

Then : it looks at `git diff eacfXX master` and `git diff eacfXX feature/2`, and see how these two diffs can be combined.

In the example you post, the solution is pretty straightforward : since there are no changes at all in `git diff eacfXX feature/2`, `git` decides that keeping the state in `master` is the way to go.

So you end up with an end result where `new_file` stays deleted.

---

The bottom line is : `git merge` does not inspect the intermediate states of the merged branches, it just tries to combine the state at the tip of the branches together.

Note however that if `new_file` had received any modifications on `feature/2` (rather than being just a verbatim copy of the original file), there would have been a merge conflict which would have prompted for a closer look.

Running `git rebase origin/master` from `feature/2` before merging would have helped, but systematically rebasing features before merging them isn't very practical, as it would add so many occasions to trigger irrelevant merge conflicts.

The generic advice is : do review your merges, be aware that, if a `git revert` of a past commit landed in the main branch, double check what the feature branch did with those same files.

Comment: Unfortunately, it happens also if I delete the file manually and commit instead of revert in steps 2. and 3. Then it can be hard to find during merge review.

Comment: @VladislavTesařík : yes, the actions you did manually introduce the exact same changes as `git revert 1; git revert 2`. The two things I mentioned in my answer : 1. rather than just running "Added new_file again", add a modification in that file (anything, even a comment, a blank line somewhere) ; when you merge you should have a conflict warning 2. after running "Added new_file again" on the `feature/2` branch, run `git rebase master`